# readystatechange using addEventListener versus old-style property?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

`readystatechange` is a standard event for `XMLHttpRequest` objects, and so should be able to have functions listen on the event either using

```
r.onreadystatechange = function() { ... };
```

as well as

```
r.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() { ... }, false);
```

However, the latter method only seems to work in Firefox and Chrome, but not Opera, which does not throw an error but simply has no effect. Why is this, and is this even correct behaviour?

Comment: It is at least defined in the W3C spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#event-handler-attributes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [MDN docs on XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) don't specifically mention raising a `readystatechange` event, but the [W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) do require it.

That combined with the general rule "`onxxx` is the event handler for event `xxx`" would imply that the Opera behaviour is incorrect.

Comment: more details on the Interface implementation of the XMLHttpRequest could help shed some light on this https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

```
xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', evt => {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        return this.responseText;
    }
}, false);
```